# Is it possible to recognize if exe is Windows Service?

Tags: c#, windows, service

I'm creating simple service manager in C# because we create services as an extensions to application. I'm able to get list of installed services with path to exe file but one of feature in wishlist is to recognize services in given path which are not installed and list them with install button.

Is there a way to recognize if exe file is Windows service?

Comment: The EXE isn't really a service until it is started as a service. Is that what you mean? If so, asking the OS the parent process might help then.

Comment: are these arbritary services? or services you have made?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I know that EXE isn't service until it's started as service. But how to find if the exe is capable to be started as service without starting it and without installing (registering it as service to Service Manager)?

Comment: @mikelegg They are made by colleagues in C#.

Comment: Then get them to do something to them that identifies them as a 'service'. E.g. special naming or something you can discover using reflection (eg an attribute). Then you just search for exe's that match whatever condition.

Comment: @mikelegg Yes that would be possible but I guess that old services won't be updated so it's solution for new one

Comment: if they have all been written in C# chances are they all contain some type eg  something that inherits from ServiceBase. So use reflection and look for this. It's a bit messy though - better to come up with an explicit scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A service has no special attributes nor properties, the only way to detect if a .exe is a service is to see if it calls one of the service functions. Looking for `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` as a string is probably the best option.

Note: If somebody knows that you are looking for this they could easily "encrypt" the StartServiceCtrlDispatcher string and bind to the function at run-time with `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: I couldn't find the `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` string and I doubt that somebody encrypted it (I can't find it even in source code of one service) but functions like `OnStart`, `OnStop`, `OnPause` are present.

Comment: Something written in .NET might be able to only use System.ServiceProcess and not end up with any native API clues in its .exe and then you would actually have to decompile its code to find out.